# How to setup Landing HTML5 page in WordPress site

Tags: html5

I have setup WordPress-oriented hosting on HostGator and I will be building a WordPress Site soon. At this point, it is a generic 'Hello World' default page. In the meantime, I found a fantastic HTML5 template for "Coming Soon" landing page.

What would be the most reasonable way to setup the "Coming Soon" HTML5 landing page? Does it make sense to try to place it 'within' WordPress or maybe remove the WordPress completely and have the HTML5 only, until the WordPress is built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, if you want to *only* show the "Coming soon" page, *and* keep working on your WordPress site at the same time, the best option is to move your WordPress installation somewhere else and only leave the HTML5 page.

Another option would be through plugins - there are plugins that exist to force all URLs on your site to go back to this special page, unless you are logged in. But you'd have to make sure the plugin in question allows you to modify the html of the default page it shows.

Any other solution that I can think of is going to be incomplete (i.e. people could still go look at mysite.com/wp-admin or any other URL they can figure out by themselves) and would prevent you from working on all or part of your site.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I went with this option. I save the code from html to index.php and modified .htaccess with the content from the html template. So, I guess it's not a wordpress site anymore :)

Answer (score 3):

shove that html into a front-page.php file and add that to your theme via ftp.  make a blank page, name it front page (or whatever) and then in settings->reading set the front page to display a static page, and make it that one.

Comment: I tried that, but the website displays just the front page from the default Wordpress Theme, not the static html5 page. Should I put something in the blank page?

Comment: You have to activate your theme...

Answer (score 0):

I would use this plugin https://tah.wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-coming-soon-page/ and add my custom CSS/HTML code and activate the plugin.

Comment: That is a very good plugin indeed! If only I could use my own template with it.